# HSQLDB prepareStatement("SET SCHEMA ?") error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, hsqldb, jbatch

I'm writing a Jbatch service that requires a connection with a HSQLDB but at a certain point it throws me a NullPointerException (and some SQLExceptions/ PersistenceExceptions) . Debugging I discovered that in the class JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.java it sets the SCHEMA to ?, but it seems like in HSQLDB it is not supported.

```
private void setSchemaOnConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        logger.finest("Entering " + CLASSNAME +".setSchemaOnConnection()");

        if (!"Oracle".equals(connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName())) {
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ps = connection.prepareStatement("SET SCHEMA ?");  -->ps = NullPointerException 
            ps.setString(1, schema);
            ps.executeUpdate(); 
            ps.close();
        }

        logger.finest("Exiting " + CLASSNAME +".setSchemaOnConnection()");
    }
```

Any ideas about how to fix it? I've already tried another databse (H2 db) but the problem is the same.

This is the full stack trace:

```
javax.batch.operations.JobStartException: com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException

    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.api.impl.JobOperatorImpl.start(JobOperatorImpl.java:92)
    at factory.jf.privacy.service.loggedareasfilter.batch.AzzaTest.testBatchChunkException(AzzaTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.services.impl.JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.createJobInstance(JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.java:1682)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.jobinstance.JobExecutionHelper.getNewJobInstance(JobExecutionHelper.java:89)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.jobinstance.JobExecutionHelper.startJob(JobExecutionHelper.java:120)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.BatchKernelImpl.startJob(BatchKernelImpl.java:124)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.api.impl.JobOperatorImpl.startInternal(JobOperatorImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.api.impl.JobOperatorImpl.start(JobOperatorImpl.java:88)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.services.impl.JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.setSchemaOnConnection(JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.java:396)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.services.impl.JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.getConnection(JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.java:334)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.services.impl.JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.createJobInstance(JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.java:1670)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The compilation of this prepared statement results in a `NullPointerExcepion` with **hsqldb**:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.result.Result.newErrorResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileSet(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    ... 42 more
```

However, when you change it to a statement without placeholders, it works:

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement("SET SCHEMA "+schema);
ps.execute();
```

Comment: he can't change the class, is in JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.java

Comment: `javax.batch.operations.JobStartException: com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: I edited the question with the full stacktrace of the exceptions

Comment: The latest HSQLDB code in SVN base/trunk supports this. You need to checkout and build the jar.